# Getting notification payload data in Ionic 2

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I have the following in my constructor in my Ionic 2 app but when I send a notification to the device nothing is triggered. I've tried with the app closed, and backgrounded. The iOS notification appears but on opening the app I don't see the alert that I'm expecting. What could I be doing wrong here?

```
this.push.rx.notification().subscribe(
        () => {
          alert('Received notification');
        }
    );
```

Comment: Getting same issue. Notification received properly. But after open, it lands on home page. as per console it is not coming in subscribe block. But app is opened it is in subscribe block. How you solved it?